# Why can I view .less file through ftp, but not http?

Tags: less

I'm wokring on a small website that I wouldlike to use Less CSS with, but I am having trouble getting the .less file to become available. If I go to the path on the server that the .less file is at through ftp, the file is there in  the browser and I can read it. However,  tag in the html is bringing me to a 404 page. If I manually type in the location through http it does not work. Why might this be happening?

Comment: Not familiar with Less CSS, is the file just called .less or is that just a suffix?

Comment: What web server are you using?  Apache, IIS, something else?

Comment: how are you including the file?

Answer (score 1):

[Requests for static files return 404 error (IIS 6.0)](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/deeac9ef-cf55-4acd-86ce-b46022ff5479.mspx)

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if i understood you correct, but: LESS is not a replacement for CSS. You must generate a CSS-file from your LESS-file to be able to serve it to the browser.

The reason why you cant view it in your browser is because the web server har no MIME-type for LESS-files, and it shouldnt have.

You can however view it through FTP cause its a "normal" text document.

Edit: You can also process the .less-file with javascript, but thats not recommended for production use...

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="less/bootstrap.less" /><script src="js/less-1.2.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>